# Creating jstree from ftp directory structure

Tags: php, ftp, jstree

I need to use jstree to display the directory structure of a ftp account's homedir.
I somehow got stuck at retrieving the full directory structure (and create a json object, xml file, html code, whatever). It is most likely something easy that is just slipping my mind, but anyway, here's what i tried so far:

```
    function draw_tree($path)
         {
           global $con;
           $list = ftp_nlist($con,$path);
           $dirs = array(); $files = array();
           foreach($list as $file)
               {
                   if(ftp_is_dir($file))
                   {
                        $dir[] = array(
                            'attr' => array('data-path' => $path . '/' . $file,
                            'data' => $file,
                            'state' => 'closed',
                            'children' => // ??? some recursive function should 
                                          // probably go here                              
                        );

                   }
                   else {
                        $files[] = array(
                               'attr' => array('data-path' => $file)
                                        );
                   }
               }
               return array_merge($dirs,$files);
         }
```

Comment: Seems like this would be a very slow page to load given you need to log into an FTP server etc... but anyway, instead of recursing the children it'd probably be better to supply a url to call to get a folders children on the fly, that way you're only fetching one level at a time :)